# LINQ equivalent for a T-SQL query

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, sql-server-2008, entity-framework-4

I have table with columns:

```
ID(int), Ano(varchar), Bno(varchar), StartTime(DateTime), EndTime(DateTime)
```

What is the equivalent LINQ statement of this SQL query:

```
 SELECT 
    StartTime, EndTime, Ano, Bno,  
    datediff(s, StartTime, EndTime) as duration 
 FROM 
    TABLENAME 
 where 
    StartTime >= 'value Input by user' 
    and StartTime <= 'value INPUT by user' 
 order by 
    StartTime desc
```

Here, how can I select duration converting to value to minutes. calculate the total of duration of all records in minute and seconds

Comment: Either you're using **Entity Framework** as your ORM - or you're using **Linq-to-SQL** instead - but you cannot use both at the same time. Which one are you really using?

Comment: entity framework 4 database first

Answer (score 2):

```
DateTime startTime = <Startime given by user>;
DateTime endTime = <Endtime given by user>;

var result = 
yourSource
  .Where (m => m.StartTime >= startTime && m.StartTime<= endTime)
  .OrderByDescending(m => m.StartTime)
  .Select(m => new {
     startTime = m.StartTime,
     endTime = m.EndTime,
     ano = m.Ano,
     bno = m.Bno,
     duration = SqlFunctions.DateDiff("mi", m.StartTime, m.EndTime)
});
```

By the way, you  could also get the result without the duration, and calculate it after retrieving the results (to avoid the anon)

Something like :

```
var duration = (EndTime - StartTime).Minutes;
```

Answer (score 1):

Match following code:

```
var result = from Entityname in EntityListName
    where Entityname.StartTime >= 'value Input by user' etc ...
    orderby Entityname.StartTime descending 
    select Entityname;
```

Comment: can we add datediff() in select

Comment: You would need something like between but AFAIK you must compare normallywith gt>= and lt<=.